# Android Trim mp4 file(remote,smb)

Tags: android, видео, ffmpeg, mp4

Есть задача по заданным временным рамкам(секунды или миллисекунды) вырезать кусочек mp4 видео. Видео лежит на другом устройстве. Оно доступно через samba(испольльзем
[jcifs](https://jcifs.samba.org/)
)

1) Попробовал найти готовую библиотеку с использование ffmpeg. Нашел [эту](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java). Как оказалось она не подlерживаете даже http. Не говоря уже о smb.

2)Попытался использовать [mp4parser](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser), но столкнулся с тем что не смог подружить jcifs и mp4parser

3)В конце концов попробовал написать свою библиотеку выполняющею эту задачу. Но это плохо решение, как подсказывают мне товарищи.

Вопрос следующий - как решить эту задачу или в каком из описанных( или мною не описанных направлений) мне стоит копать. Попытаться самому собрат ffmpeg и адоптировать его под андройд или я недостаточно хорошо изучил  mp4parser? Может самописная библиотека не такое плохое решение?

Comment: Скачать файл на устройство любым способом, запустить команду ffmpeg с нужными параметрами, загрузить получившийся файл куда надо любым способом?

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий, но необходимо скачать только часть файла к себе.